# masonry layout with css flex not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox, masonry

I have following situation where css flex based masonry displayed images overflowing the parent div's width. It is supposed to go downwards like a normal Masonry.... but I can't figure it out how to fix this.

[image]

I wrote my code like below...

HTML

```
<div class="mansory-gallery">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/4861550688/" target="_blank"><img src="http://minoboshitaro.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/51AEWKP5CQL._SX339_BO1204203200_.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.mansory-gallery {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 100vw;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.item {
    width: 28%;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.mansory-gallery a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: .8s opacity;
    height: auto;
}
```

Please let me know how to solve this!
Thank you for your time!

Comment: Provide a minimal working code snippet reproducing the issue.

Comment: Check this out: [complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Maybe that helps?

Comment: I can't quite tell the issue here but maybe this could help - https://codepen.io/nhensh/pen/OZRgYa I am removing margins and using `justify-content: space-around;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `justify-content: space-around;` instead of margins.

```
 .mansory-gallery {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    max-height: 100vw;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.item {
    width: 28%;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.mansory-gallery a img {
    max-width: 100%;
    transition: .8s opacity;
    height: auto;
}
```

Example - https://codepen.io/nhensh/pen/OZRgYa